# What is the R code for the following Data set

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set which has products and their quantity sold. I want to write a R code which tells me the best selling product.

```
Products              Quantity

Laminated               520
Laminated               150
Laminated               639
Laminated               702
SUPERSTAR                 3
TAMAX                   500
TAMAX                    20
TAMAX                    40
GreenDragon              40
GreenDragon              50
XPLODE                   40
XPLODE                   20
EXPERT                   40
KHANJARBIOSL             40
```

Here just by looking the data set we can say laminated is the best product in terms of quantity sold. Can we write an R code for this.

Thanks

Comment: Define "best"..

Comment: In terms of quantity sold

Comment: @barbarian I don't know what you are doing, but I think you are looking for `table()`.

Comment: I have a large data set with 300+ unique products, my objective is to find that product which has sold the most in terms of quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to do this. One way using `tapply` is to get `sum` of `Quantity` for each `Product`, get the name of the maximum value.

```
names(which.max(tapply(df$Quantity, df$Products, sum, na.rm  = TRUE)))
#[1] "Laminated"
```

Comment: Thanks. Also is there a way that I can sort this data set based on the quantity of products sold. Like first will be Laminated second will be Tamax and third will be Greendragon

Comment: Yes, you can do `names(sort(tapply(df$Quantity, df$Products, sum, na.rm  = TRUE), decreasing = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.table package. First do the sum, then sort it in descending order based on aggregated value. Then fetch first row.

```
tb = data.frame("Products" =c("Laminated", "Laminated", "Laminated", "Laminated", "SUPERSTAR", "TAMAX", "TAMAX", "TAMAX", "GreenDragon", "GreenDragon", "XPLODE", "XPLODE", "EXPERT", "KHANJARBIOSL"), "Quantity" = c(520,150,639,702,3,500,20,40,40,50,40,20,40,40))


library(data.table)

tb = data.table(tb)

tb[,sum(Quantity), by="Products"][order(-V1)][1]
```